# Load a binary into flash memory using gdb

Tags: arm, gdb

I'd like to flash a binary file into my ARM MCU flash memory using gdb.

Currently I'm able to load an elf like this:

```
# arm-none-eabi-gdb --command=flash.gdb "myfirmware.elf"

# cat flash.gdb
set confirm off
target remote 127.0.0.1:7224
monitor reset
load
detach
quit
```

Basically the `load` command is good at loading elf sections to the right addresses.

However to put multiple firmware in the MCU flash memory, I'd like to send a complete binary image.
In order to test it, I made a zero.bin image (containing nothing but 0):

```
# hexdump zero.bin
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0020000


# arm-none-eabi-gdb
(gdb) target remote 127.0.0.1:7224
(gdb) mon reset halt
(gdb) mon reset init
(gdb) set arm fallback-mode auto
(gdb) set debug arm
(gdb) restore zero.bin binary 0x0
Restoring binary file zero.bin into memory (0x0 to 0x20000)
Writing to flash memory forbidden in this context
(gdb) info mem                                                                                                         
Using memory regions provided by the target.                                                              
Num Enb Low Addr   High Addr  Attrs                                                                      
0   y   0x00000000 0x00020000 flash blocksize 0x800 nocache                                              
1   y   0x00020000 0x100000000 rw nocache        
(gdb) delete mem 1
warning: Switching to manual control of memory regions; use "mem auto" to fetch regions from the target again.
(gdb) delete mem 0
(gdb) mem 0 0x100000000 rw nocache
(gdb) info mem
Using user-defined memory regions.
Num Enb Low Addr   High Addr  Attrs
1   y   0x00000000 0x100000000 rw nocache
(gdb) restore zero.bin binary 0x0
Restoring binary file zero.bin into memory (0x0 to 0x20000)
(gdb) x/10 0x0
0x0:    0x20003000      0x00003c5d      0x00003c7d      0x00003c7d
0x10:   0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x20:   0x00000000      0x00000000
```

So this doesn't seem to work, as you can see in 0x0 it should be full of '0' but it still contains my previous firmware (the vector table actually)

What do I miss? Or maybe there is another way to load a binary using gdb?

Comment: The restore command failed with `Writing to flash memory forbidden in this context`.  I'm trying to figure out why this happens for me as well

Comment: Actually in my case, it was because this zone is mapped to the flash memory, and gdb needs a way to figure out how to program the flash it could not be something like `addr[i] = data[i]`. I don't know how to setup gdb to do that though. Anyway, hope it helps!

Comment: Flash requires special sequences to program.  It is not clear if it is NOR or NAND flash.  In *gdb*, `help restore` indicates that the file is just written.  However, flash requires unlocks, erases and byte/word program commands.  `restore` will not do this.  You need to call a different function to program flash; it will depend on the hardware.  The supplied (un-accepted) answers give ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **OpenOCD**,

```
mon flash write_bank <num> <file_name> <offset>
```

should help you.

For example, if your flash starts at `0x400000`,

`mon flash write_bank 0 zero.bin 0x100000`

will write the zero.bin file at `0x500000`, assuming that address is writable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete memory region. Because GDB uses `vFlashWrite` packet for writing to flash memory and `M or X` packets for writing to RAM.

I know only one way to write binary data to flash memory using gdb.
You need to transform your binary image to elf-file with one single `.data` section.

`powerpc-objcopy -I binary -O elf32-powerpc -B PowerPC -S zero.bin zero.elf`

For checking your new elf-file use `readelf`.

`powerpc-readelf -h -t zero.elf`

In the end just use `load` command with flash base address, because this elf-file has not any address information. (or you can use --change-addresses 0x0 option with objcopy)

`load zero.elf 0x0`

I checked this on PowerPC. GDB version is 8.1.

`This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=powerpc-eabi".`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gdb or gdb-multiarch, you can try the following python script;

```
# Specify the path to the binary file and the target memory address
binary_file = "firmware.bin"
memory_address = 0x20000000

# Open the binary file for reading
with open(binary_file, "rb") as file:
    # Read the file contents
    file_contents = file.read()

    # Convert the file contents to a list of integers
    file_bytes = list(file_contents)

    # Write the file contents to the target memory address
    for i, byte in enumerate(file_bytes):
        gdb.selected_inferior().write_memory(memory_address + i, bytes([byte]))
```

- Save as write_memory.py
- Start GDB
- Connect target device(target remote localhost:)
- Load your application symbols and add breakpoint if you need
- Execute write_memory.py script using source command within GDB like below;

> (gdb) source write_memory.py

Now you can check the first 10 bytes of memory with the following gdb command;

> (gdb) x/10x 0x20000000

That's all. I hope it will be useful.