# How to implement modular hardware unit tests in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, embedded, tdd, eclipse-cdt

I work with embedded systems and I'm doing bare metal programming. For my target microcontroller, the manufacturer recommends to code in C or C++ and to use their customized version of Eclipse to compile the code, program the chip and debug.

As development technique, I'm trying to use [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), so I'm coding modules at the same time I'm creating unit tests for that module.

And, due to the nature of embedded systems, I'm splitting my tests in two distinct groups:

1. **Software unit tests**: in these tests, I create software mocks or fakes to simulate all the hardware accesses. This way, I can run the tests on a PC, using any test framework I want. These tests are working fine.
2. **Hardware unit tests**: in these tests, I check if I really understood the library the manufacturer provided to do hardware access and/or I check if I can control correctly the hardware in my board. Those tests need to run in the target processor, so I need to compile then in Eclipse. <-- **Here I'm facing problems**.

To code my first module interacting with the hardware, I created a new eclipse project, exclusively to compile the corresponding hardware unit test. In this new project, I created links to the folders necessary to the module, excluded from build the code unrelated to the module, then I created a new file with `main()` and after that, the test run as intended. That was fine.

To implement the second module, I did the same as the first module and the test ran as intended too. However, after implementing the second module, the first project stopped compiling.

The trouble in the first project appeared because Eclipse detected a new source file (used in the second module) in a shared directory, tried to compile this intruder source file, and then broke due to dependency errors.

Since Eclipse seems to compile everything that is in a directory and, to advance my development, I need to keep inserting files in a shared directory, I don't know how continue implementing those modular hardware test without reworking previous tests for each new module. Does anyone know?

### Example of the problem

Below I show a simplified example of the problem, since there are some modules already implemented without unit tests.

#### First module: SPI

When I finished SPI module, the files were:

```
my_project
├── src/
│   ├── config/
│   │   ├── config_clk.c
│   │   ├── config_spi.c
│   │   └── config_spi.h
│   └── hal/
│       └── spi/
│           ├── spi.c
│           └── spi.h
└── test/
    └── spi/    (Location of the SPI test project)
        ├── .cproject
        ├── .project
        ├── test_spi_custom_config_clk.c
        └── test_spi_main.cpp
```

I create a new project, created links to folders `src/hal/spi` and `src/config`, excluded the file `src/config/config_clk.c` and this ran fine.

#### Second module: EEPROM

When I finished EEPROM module, the files were:

```
my_project
├── src/
│   ├── config/
│   │   ├── config_clk.c
│   │   ├── config_eeprom.c
│   │   ├── config_eeprom.h
│   │   ├── config_spi.c
│   │   └── config_spi.h
│   └── hal/
│       ├── eeprom/
│       │   ├── eeprom.c
│       │   └── eeprom.h
│       └── spi/
│           ├── spi.c
│           └── spi.h
└── test/
    ├── eeprom/    (Location of the EEPROM test project)
    │   ├── .cproject
    │   ├── .project
        ├── test_eeprom_custom_config_eeprom.c
    │   └── test_eeprom_main.cpp
    └── spi/    (Location of the SPI test project)
        ├── .cproject
        ├── .project
        ├── test_spi_custom_config_clk.c
        └── test_spi_main.cpp
```

I create a new project, created links to folders `src/hal/eeprom` and `src/config`, excluded the files `src/config/config_clk.c` and `src/config/config_spi.c` and this ran fine.

However, when I try to run the first test, Eclipse tries to compile `src/config/config_eeprom.c` and it breaks because config_eeprom.c depends on eeprom.h or something else.

So It is clear this is not a sustainable approach.

Comment: I've found CMake + VSCode + appropriate plugins allows for a decent IDE and modular (and source control friendly) build system with built in CTest support.    I haven't had a lot of luck debugging on the target from VSCode, but we prefer the vendor debugging environment.   We just keep out of eclipse and proprietary make junk as much as possible

Comment: Apparently you are using managed C projects that allow exactly one target per project, and only an executable. I'm using Eclipse since 20+ years for embedded control development (and more), and I'm always using Makefile projects. This enables you to use more than one target (= executable or log file or abstract target) per project, and decouples you from any type of IDE. The "target" view is the best help here, and I like Eclipse's capabilities for source control, source navigation, refactoring, general project management.

Comment: @RussSchultz, I would like to stop using Eclipse, but we haven't found a way to program this microcontroller without Eclipse yet. I usually code in VS Code then I compile, program and debug in Eclipse. I could try to compile with CMake, but then I still have to learn how to program the chip.

Comment: Actually, you can handle this kind of project with any editor and from the command line. This works perfectly fine, even with strange targets like 8051 controllers, and Keil's µVision simulator for hardware unit tests and system tests, which need to run with the real target code. The most elaborated project had a mixture of all of this, multiple production targets, unit tests running on the PC, unit tests running on the simulator, system tests running on the simulator, and systems tests launched on a real system.

Comment: And Eclipse supports me by a simple way to add error parsers for strange compilers, and assigning the simulator script file type for syntax coloring (fortunately it is a kind of C). But all of this is subjective. My final line is: **Create a real Makefile project with multiple targets.**

Comment: If you don't know how to develop without Eclipse, I suggest to learn it. A better understanding of the development process is necessary to master any project. Eclipse is "just" an IDE, as VSC is "just" a blown-up editor.

Comment: I've just found some links pointing to OpenOCD + gdb to program the microcontroler: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46052375/1669975), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60245257/1669975) and [link3](https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/gdb/como-usar-o-gdb-gnu-debugger-e-openocd-para-depuracao-do-microcontrolador-partir-do-terminal/825824258/) (in Portuguese). I'll try to follow these links to learn how to use a solution independent from Eclipse.

Comment: @thebusybee, thank you for the incentive. You are absolutely right. I've been to much time siting just in the steering wheel of this car. For the level I want to develop it's time to go to the engine itself.

Comment: Since Eclipse commonly uses make to build its target, all command lines are shown in the console view. This is always a good starting point.